# Issue with math font while using beamer

Tags: beamer, math-fonts

I am having issue with math font while using beamer. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[x11names]{beamer}
\usepackage{bm,fontenc,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}  
\begin{equation*} h_{\mathtt{x}}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\exp{\Big(\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\bm{\mu})^{\mathtt{T}} \bm{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x}-\bm{\mu})^{}\Big)}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^2\begin{vmatrix}\bm{\Sigma}\end{vmatrix}}} 
\end{equation*} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and its output

[image]

How can I get an output like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[x11names]{beamer}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{bm,fontenc,amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}  
\begin{equation*} h_{\mathtt{x}}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\exp{\Big(\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\bm{\mu})^{\mathtt{T}} \bm{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x}-\bm{\mu})^{}\Big)}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^2\begin{vmatrix}\bm{\Sigma}\end{vmatrix}}} 
\end{equation*} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]